# Using script without disabling "script.disable_dynamic" in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to use a single script , but i dont want to disable script.disable_dynamic
Disabling this would be an invitation for hackers to bring my machine down.
Is there any way , i can achieve this ?

Comment: I dont know what is your server design but i would put the ES server behind a firewall. each request to the ES should be done from the ES's lan. Also create a "facade" (as a new server in the ES's lan but with access to wan) that will make the ES queries request. that way you will be able to call the script without the threat that someone will be able to run a remote script from outside the lan. In addition make sure that you give the right privileges to the user the runs the elasticsearch read more here http://brudtkuhl.com/securing-elasticsearch/

Comment: what version of elasticsearch are you using?

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways to achieve this -

1. Copy your scripts under config/scripts folder - This way the scripts would be pre compiled and you can access them using their name. You can read more info [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html).
2. You can write the java code for the script functionality and package it as a plugin.

You can read more about the same [here](http://blog.qbox.io/introduction-to-elasticsearch-scripting).